# Port-forwarding and website hosting: Two domains, same ip, different computer

Tags: http, networking, web, dns, ip

So I have two domains:
http://firstexample.com
http://secondexample.com

on my router I currently have portforwarding so that when someone goes to http://firstexample.com, they see the website that my computer with internal IP 192.168.0.15 is hosting

How can I set it up so that if someone goes to http://secondexample.com, they would see the website that my other computer, with internal ip 192.168.0.16 is hosting?

Both of my computers have the same public IP.

Is it a setting on my router I would change? Or would godaddy allow me to configure something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to listen for two domains on the same IP/port configuration, using just Layer3/4 functionality alone. Most of the web servers do it based on the `Host` field in the request. If you are okay with using two ports on your router, that's possible eg. you can do something like following port forwarding

```
<router_ip>:80 -> 192.168.0.15:80 
<router_ip>:8080 -> 192.168.0.16:80
```

But the problem with that is anyone trying to access http://secondexample.com should always access it as http://secondexample.com:8080 which is very inconvenient.

Here's another alternative you can do -

run a webserver on say `192.168.0.15` like `nginx` or something and create two backends one for each http://firstexample.com and http://secondexample.com . Refer nginx docs for how to do it.  You'd not need three machines for that firstexample.com can run on `192.168.0.15` (except not on a standard port 80 but on a port 8080 say) and secondexample.com would run on another machine. And then add only following entry on your router port forwarding

```
<router_ip>:80 -> 192.168.0.15:80 # assuming ngninx is listening on port 80.
```

I am assuming both firstexample.com and secondexample.com do resolve to your router IP address.